# How to reduce capturing time in raspberry pi camera?

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, pi-b+

I am working on a program on raspberry pi b+ model, my program needs to capture images from a raspberry pi camera attached i used this code to capture images:

```
cmd='raspistill -o '+filename+' -t 10 -ex auto -awb auto -w 800 -h 600 '
pid=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

when i tested this code the time for running just these two lines of code was about 1 second and this is way too much time

my question: is there any way to reduce time of capturing images, or is there any other features that can be added to the code to reduce the time of capturing ?

Comment: You can try to stream video to a dump, and capture stills on request from the buffer. That should be instant... but the code may be challenging and require you to do something in C using the API's